# Microsoft Speech Recognition in web service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, speech-recognition

I'm trying to use the System.Speech.Recognition namespace for recognizing speech in a web service. Actually, the WS calls a dll that uses this namespace.

The problem is that...I can't. First, I had a Access denied error. After changing the Identity of my application pool to LocalSystem (security break, I know), that disappeared. But a timeout appeared. I receive no error, but no response either.

I did some tests, and, the same code (very simple) that I use for recognizing the text in a WAV returns the answer in around 2 seconds, when integrated in a desktop application, but hangs and does nothing in a web application.

I think I'm missing something... I'm not supposed to use  System.Speech.Recognition in a web application? Am I supposed to use something else?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this post [Do I need to install Speech SDK to be able to do speech recognition, even when I'm using .NET Speech Recognition namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636203/do-i-need-to-install-speech-sdk-to-be-able-to-do-speech-recognition-even-when-i) has the answer you need.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I looked at the article, but it is treating a different problem. In my case, I can use the System.Speech.Recognition namespace with no problem in a desktop application, but when I try to run the exact same code in a web application, I get not response.

Comment: Link-only answers are the bad.

Answer (score -1):

What operating system are you running on? Not all windows OSes include speech recognizers. Use the method System.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognitionEngine.InstalledRecognizers() to find all the installed desktop speech recognizers you have installed.

You ask

> I'm not supposed to use
>   System.Speech.Recognition in a web
>   application? Am I supposed to use
>   something else?

I never tried to run the System.Speech calls under ASP.NET, but Microsoft does provide a separate (but very similar) API for server speech. See the Microsoft.Speech namespace which is part of SpeechServer, OCS, and UCMA.

See if http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=b20967b1-6cf5-4a4b-b7ae-622653ac929f&displaylang=en helps.